# QGIS 3.4.8 Filter Expression for OSM values

Tags: qgis-3, filter

I'm trying to complete the seemingly basic task of a filter select for a layer of OSM data pulled from https://download.openstreetmap.fr/extracts/africa/. It's an .osm.pbf which I added to my project as a vector layer. The file is 21.7MB.

The layer's attribute table contains an 'other_tags' column. In that column, some rows include the word 'power'; e.g.

- "frequency"=>"50","cables"=>"3","voltage"=>"110000","power"=>"line"
- "power"=>"generator","generator:source"=>"hydro"

I simply want to select all rows with "power" in this field. This should be the query:

```
other_tags LIKE '%power%'
```

I've also tried:

```
"other_tags" LIKE '%power%'
other_tags ILIKE '%power%'
"other_tags" ILIKE '%power%'
other_tags IS '%power%'
"other_tags" IS '%power%'
```

This is driving me crazy. I've read the QGIS docs and numerous Posts on StackExhange, so beginning to wonder if it's a QGIS bug.

Comment: How are you importing this into QGIS? For example osm2shp, osm2pgsql, ogr2ogr, or something else? This looks like an hstore field... If you're storing in postgres you might need to use [special operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/hstore.html) to query the existence of tags. Can you check the field type of 'other_tags' in the layer properties, is that field of type string?

Comment: @StevenKay - I'm simply doing an `Add Vector Layer` of the .osm.pbf file direct into QGIS. The attribute table looks like [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/yAwxb4iFLcMcQtLs6).

Comment: A screenshot of the attribute table doesn't tell us what the field types are. You can check the field type *in the layer properties*.

Comment: @StevenKay, @csk - Another screen shot [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YzU3PQAH41xbWMJ28). `other tags` is of Type = QString, Type name = String.

Answer (score 1):

This webpage explains the reason why QGIS expression doesn't work and a solution for it: [Using OSM Data in QGIS](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm-in-qgis/)

In a nutshell, in order to use an OSM tag named `tag`:

- If the tag is a column in its own right, use `tag`
- Otherwise, use `hstore_to_map(other_tags)['tag']`

For your use case, `hstore_to_map(other_tags)['power'] is not null` should do the trick.

Comment: This is a link-only answer: you should add the main message the linked site contributes to the problem. If the link is dead, the solution will be lost.